# Hikaricp Timer already cancelled

Tags: postgresql, datasource, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I have an application that uses Hikaricp to create a data source and connect to database. I have used the following defaults of Hikaricp.

```
#Default properties for HikariCp
hikari.maximumPoolSize=100
hikari.maxLifetime=3600000
hikari.minimumIdle=1
hikari.connectionTimeout=1800000
hikari.testQuery=SELECT 1
```

The data source is created with the database details when there is a request for a connection. And once the data source is created, its reference is cached and used for subsequent database interactions(as data sources need not be created time and again).

Usually I am not facing any issues. But, sometimes facing this Timer already cancelled issues. In this case the database is postgresql. The following is the stacktrace.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.
    at java.util.Timer.sched(Timer.java:397)
    at java.util.Timer.schedule(Timer.java:193)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.addTimerTask(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:1357)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.startTimer(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:3478)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:615)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:452)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:332)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.isConnectionAlive(HikariPool.java:132)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.getConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:208)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.getConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:183)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:133)
    at com.mycompany.efwd.jdbc.DataSourceConnectionProvider.a(SourceFile:84)
    at com.mycompany.efwd.jdbc.DataSourceConnectionProvider.b(SourceFile:65)
    ... 99 more
```

Can someone throw light on why is this issue and how can I resolve?

Comment: All I can tell you is that HikariCP is setting a query timeout in this scenario via Statement.setQueryTimeout().  It seems likely to me that this is a bug in the PostgreSQL driver.  Quite possibly for extremely short queries, or in the event that the connection has already closed server-side ... and therefore the Timer object for that connection is already cancelled.  I recommend reporting this as a bug to PostgreSQL.  They are very responsive, and your stacktrace is likely enough for them to solve the issue.  I am the author of HikariCP, tell them I sent you.

Comment: @brettw I will post a bug. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: @phoenix Did you ever create a bug? And/or was it ever resolved?

Answer (score 2):

It is probably because you use opentracing.
Just remove opentracing from your dependencies. It is the best way I find for me.