# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.: Oracle database

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Hi I am connecting to oracle database. Using spring boot 2.3.3.,spring-data-jpa. On my local it is working fine ad the application is connecting to the database. But when i am creating docker image and deploying it on Kubernetes, it is giving me this error

```
    05:28:08.536 [main] INFO c.o.e.a.t.events.EventService - establishing kafka event streams

05:28:10.450 [main] INFO c.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...

05:28:11.715 [main] ERROR c.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.

at java.base/java.util.Timer.sched(Timer.java:398)

at java.base/java.util.Timer.schedule(Timer.java:194)

at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutInterruptHandler.scheduleInterrupt(TimeoutInterruptHandler.java:90)

at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutInterruptHandler.scheduleInterrupt(TimeoutInterruptHandler.java:103)

at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.scheduleInterrupt(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:235)

at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.connect(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:97)

at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.<init>(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:77)

at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:192)

at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:174)

at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:510)

at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:548)

at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:682)

at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:309)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1596)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:588)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:793)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:57)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:747)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:562)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eeb1ae86.invoke(<generated>)

at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)

at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)

at io.opentracing.contrib.spring.cloud.jdbc.JdbcAspect.getConnection(JdbcAspect.java:56)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)

at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)

at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)

at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)

at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8e61f198.getConnection(<generated>)

at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)

at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)

at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)

at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)

at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)

at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)

at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)

at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)

at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)

at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)

at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)

at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)

at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176)

at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118)

at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224)

at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255)

at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)

at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)

at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)

at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)

at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109)

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)

at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)

at com.optum.ses.peo.paas.api.DBAutomationAPIApplication.main(DBAutomationAPIApplication.java:16)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)

at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)

at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)

at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)

at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)

05:28:11.719 [main] WARN o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Failed to initialize pool: Timer already cancelled.

05:28:12.953 [main] INFO c.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...

05:28:13.958 [main] ERROR c.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.

at java.base/java.util.Timer.sched(Timer.java:398)

at java.base/java.util.Timer.schedule(Timer.java:194)

at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutInterruptHandler.scheduleInterrupt(TimeoutInterruptHandler.java:90)

at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutInterruptHandler.scheduleInterrupt(TimeoutInterruptHandler.java:103)

at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.scheduleInterrupt(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:235)

at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.connect(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:97)

at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.<init>(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:77)

at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:192)

at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:174)

at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:510)

at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:548)

at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:682)

at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:309)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1596)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:588)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:793)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:57)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:747)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:562)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eeb1ae86.invoke(<generated>)

at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)

at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)

at io.opentracing.contrib.spring.cloud.jdbc.JdbcAspect.getConnection(JdbcAspect.java:56)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)

at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)

at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)

at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)

at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8e61f198.getConnection(<generated>)

at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158)

at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116)

at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)

at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324)

at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:120)

at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.lambda$isInitializingDatabase$0(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:116)

at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateSettings.getDdlAuto(HibernateSettings.java:41)

at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineDdlAuto(HibernateProperties.java:136)

at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.getAdditionalProperties(HibernateProperties.java:102)

at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(HibernateProperties.java:94)

at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.isInitializingDatabase(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:118)

at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:98)

at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:90)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:430)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1798)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109)

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)

at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)

at com.optum.ses.peo.paas.api.DBAutomationAPIApplication.main(DBAutomationAPIApplication.java:16)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)

at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)

at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)

at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)

at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)

05:28:13.961 [main] WARN o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'secondaryEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/optum/ses/peo/paas/api/Configuration/CmdbConfig.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Timer already cancelled.

05:28:14.344 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'secondaryEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/optum/ses/peo/paas/api/Configuration/CmdbConfig.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Timer already cancelled.

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109)

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)

at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)

at com.optum.ses.peo.paas.api.DBAutomationAPIApplication.main(DBAutomationAPIApplication.java:16)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)

at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)

at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)

at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)

at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)

Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Timer already cancelled.

at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(HikariPool.java:595)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:581)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eeb1ae86.invoke(<generated>)

at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)

at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)

at io.opentracing.contrib.spring.cloud.jdbc.JdbcAspect.getConnection(JdbcAspect.java:56)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)

at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)

at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)

at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)

at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8e61f198.getConnection(<generated>)

at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158)

at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116)

at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)

at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324)

at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:120)

at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.lambda$isInitializingDatabase$0(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:116)

at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateSettings.getDdlAuto(HibernateSettings.java:41)

at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineDdlAuto(HibernateProperties.java:136)

at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.getAdditionalProperties(HibernateProperties.java:102)

at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(HibernateProperties.java:94)

at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.isInitializingDatabase(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:118)

at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:98)

at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:90)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:430)
```

Here is my code:

pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>19.3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@XVZ.XYZ.com:1521/XYZ.XYZ.com?serverTimezone=CST6CDT
spring.datasource.username=name
spring.datasource.password=pwd
spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you have more lines of your Stack Trace? it does not look complete.

Additionally it could be a consequential error (some error, timer is canceled, BAM your error). Are there any other errors in the logs?

Comment: @JensBaitinger Hi.. I have added complete error logs. I am just seeing this error only.

Comment: Is the DB up and running? I suspect this might be a timing issue. Also, the stack trace mentioned `secondaryEntityManagerFactory`, are there other EMFs connecting to the same DB?

Comment: Yes Db is runnning. Also when i am running the application from intellij, it runs smoothly. @crizzis

Comment: Was this fixed? If yes, please provide the details

Comment: a note - but maybe not the same case - i've seen this error pop up out of a sudden while working with Netbeans 12, Java 8 and external Tomcat 9 server, while connected to Oracle and trying to retrieve data from database via JDBC calls. the only way for me to get it go away was to restart Netbeans.

Comment: The solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64973739/4003272 helped me.